# Python lists: indices of heapq.nlargest with repeating values in list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of numbers:

```
my_list = [3, 8, 4, 2, 8, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1]
```

I now want to find the indices of the 2 greatest numbers in this list. So, I try:

```
import heapq
max_vals = heapq.nlargest(2, my_list)
index1 = my_list.index(max_vals[0])
index2 = my_list.index(max_vals[1])
print index1
print index2
```

Here, both `index1`and `index2` are `1`. This is because `max_vals` has `8` for both values, and the `my_list.index()` just searches for the first instance of `8`.

How can I get the indices of the top 2 values in this case, such that `index1` is `1` as before, but `index2` is now `4`, corresponding to the other `8` in the list?

On a side note, it seems rather inefficient to find the maximum value in a list, and then subsequently find the index of that value. Is there not a way to achieve this in one sweep of the list?

Thank you.

Comment: What if the list has *three* 8s?

Comment: @mgilson: then `heapq.nlargest` is documented to return the first two, since it is documented to be equivalent to `sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]`, and `sorted` is a stable sort. Not that you could tell the difference when the contents are small integers, since any two `int` with value `8` have the same identity in CPython, but it at least suggests what the answer should be in terms of the indexes returned :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop -- I get what will happen with `heapq` -- I was more interested if OP had thought about that and if taking the first 2 `8` values was the desired result, or if OP actually then wants all 3 `8` values.

Answer (score 10):

You can apply `heapq.nlargest` on `enumerate(list)`"

```
>>> import heapq
>>> data = heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(my_list), key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> indices, vals = zip(*data)
>>> indices
(1, 4)
>>> vals
(8, 8)
```

Comment: and `heapq.nlargest(2, range(len(my_list)), key=my_list.__getitem__)` to get just the indices.